# How to enable the Wi-Fi network adapter "Intel AC 3168 " in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi

I bought a new laptop, removed the internal hard drive from my old laptop and put it into the new one. Ubuntu 16 in general works fine but it does not recognize the Wi-Fi network adapter in the new computer. Connecting to the internet with an Ethernet cable works fine. Neither the network manager nor the network settings seem to be aware that the laptop has a wireless antenna.

Dual booting in Windows shows the wireless hardware works fine. Booting Ubuntu from a USB stick also finds the wireless and connects without problems. From the Ubuntu wireless troubleshooting, if I use `lspci -v`, it finds the network controller, device name is “Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter”, but `nmcli dev` shows only the Ethernet controller but nothing Wi-Fi related.

How can I tell Ubuntu to look through the hardware, find the Wi-Fi network controller, and if needed load the drivers for it?

Comment: Please edit [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/403739/edit) by adding the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Also show the output of **rfkill list all**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the wifi working for *Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168* you should:

1) Upgrade your kernel version to a kernel version >= 4.6+

2) Download a copy the firmware to your `/lib/firmware`

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0
sudo cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Intel website: [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Comment: This worked, thanks. Had to google how to do a kernel upgrade and then go through the command line to do it. Is there a better way (ie graphic user interface) to do it? Also had to add a 'sudo' for the last two lines of step 2) to get admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from USB, figure out what module it's using with `lsmod`, then reboot and `modprobe` that. If it works, you can make it load automatically by creating a file in `/etc/modprobe.d`, see `man modprobe.d` for how to do that.